# Can I perform my own yajnas?

Tags: rituals, rig-veda, yajna, vedic-rituals, vedic-chanting

I was wondering if I can perform my own yajnas if I know the Mantras and Rituals. I'm a Kshatriya by guna (not by surname). That's why I would like to know if I'm eligible to do my own yajnas, since no Brahmana today knows Vedic rituals.

Comment: Very few yajnas can be performed without Brahmins.e.g. Agnihotra homa.

Comment: @ArtistFormerlyKnownAsCSD Even if I practice the Mantras and study the methodology of rituals?

Comment: Yes, even then you need brahmins